# PySide QThread and QProgressBar

Tags: python, multithreading, qt, user-interface, pyside

I'm kinda new in GUI programming with PySide, and in Python GUI in general.
I'm trying to set a progress bar value using a thread, but it doesn't work and there is these errors that keeps on appearing:

```
 QPixmap: It is not safe to use pixmaps outside the GUI thread
```

or

```
 QWidget::repaint: Recursive repaint detected
```

And the program crashes suddenly especially when I'm trying to interact with another widget in the gui.

---

The following is not the actual code, it's only a simulation of what I wanted to do:

```
from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtCore import *​​
import os, time, platform, sys
class main(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(main, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(300, 100)
        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(300, 100))
        self.setMaximumSize(QSize(300, 100))
        self.setWindowTitle("Test")
        self.buttonStart = QPushButton("Start")
        self.progressBar = QProgressBar()
        self.gridLayout = QGridLayout(self)
        self.setLayout(self.gridLayout)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.progressBar, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.buttonStart, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.connect(self.buttonStart, SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.startProgress)
        self.genericThread = GenericThread(self.test)
    def startProgress(self):
        self.genericThread.start()
    def test(self):
        print "started"
        for i in range(100):
            time.sleep(0.3)
            print i
            self.progressBar.setValue(i)
        print "done"
class GenericThread(QThread):
    def __init__(self, function, *args, **kwargs):
        QThread.__init__(self)
        self.function = function
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
    def run(self):
        self.function(*self.args,**self.kwargs)
        return
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
start = main()
start.show()
app.exec_()
```

So, the GenericThread is supposed to run any function passed into it in a thread, instead of creating a thread for each function. I know that I should be using signals to make a thread change a widget in the gui thread, but actually I failed to apply that with this thread class. I tried to add the signal to the test function, and connect it to the main class, but it didn't do anything.

So what should I do? I don't want to change the thread class GenericThread, as the actual code has many functions that need to be run in separate threads, and at the same time I need to show the thread's progress to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Use a signal to the gui thread to have it update the progress bar and/or draw the Pixmap.

And when you connect that signal, make sure that you tell it to use a `Qt::QueuedConnection`, instead of a `Qt::AutoConnection`.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qobject.html#connect

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents

Hope that helps.